# Big O complexity of nested loop depending on changing fraction result

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

Being relatively new to Big-Oh Notation and complexity analysis, I have been asked to determine the Big-Oh (tightest upper bound) time complexity of the following code.

Now as far as I can tell, for every iteration after the very first one (for which it would only run exactly once) the inner loop runs x2 meaning x times.
In itself this would be O(x).

y is never changed throughout the entire execution of the algorithm. However, n is incremented in every iteration, which affects the exit condition of the outer loop.

Because of the constant incrementation of n, the fraction serving as the exit condition of the outer loop becomes smaller and smaller.

Now if there was something like y/=2, and not y/n, every single time, I would immediately go for O(log y) runtime of the outer loop, but because of the changing denominator I'm thinking that we could view this as a factor, which --according to what I know about Big-Oh-- can be ignored, hence O(y) complexity of the outer loop, meaning O(x*y) complexity of the whole method.

Could anybody provide me with some guidance or a few tips regarding this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

```
    void a (long x, long y){
      long n = 0, x2 = n;
      do {
        do {
          x2--;
        } while (x2 > 0);
       n++;
       x2 = x;
      } while (n < y / n);
   }
```

EDIT: Thanks everybody for helping me out. Just as a little follow-up question: What would be the big-o complexity if the code were instead written like this:

```
    void a(int x, int y) {
        int n = 1;
        do {
            x++;
            n++;
        } while(y/n > x);
    }
```

I tried rearranging it a little (e.g. y > n*x) and thinking of n as a constant that could be dropped which led me to believe that this would be O(y), but I feel like there is something I just don't yet understand about how these fractional conditions can be expressed in big O notation.

Comment: `n < y / n` implies `n * n < y` (rounding is usually irrelevant in big-O) - what does this suggest about the complexity of the outer loop?

Comment: and the inner loop technically loops, practically it just sets `x2` to something close to `Math.min(x2 - 1, 1)`. And the result is ignored anyway since `x2` and `x` are unused.

Comment: Does this code actually have any purpose other than an academic study of Big O?

Comment: @ meowgoesthedog : Thanks for pointing this out. So I guess its O(sqrt(y)) for the outer loop meaning O(x * sqrt(y)) for the whole thing...?

Comment: @Dbadtf_385 correct. (btw, theoretical questions like this are perfectly fine as long as they are programming-related and you show what you have tried)

Comment: @jarmod given that the function returns nothing and doesn't call any external functions...

Comment: @ jarmod: Actually it probably doesn't. Is that a problem though? Just asking as a stackoverflow newbie if I have to flag these questions differently next time

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing things up, not just the question but in terms of stackoverflow conduct as well.

Comment: @Dbadtf_385 No, not a problem at all. Just wondering if this was a real fragment of  code from some larger algorithm that actually did something useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Could anybody provide me with some guidance or a few tips regarding this?

When in doubt count the operations performed.

For the purposes of complexity analysis<sup>1</sup>, it is a safe assumption that any primitive operation (arithmetic, test, branch) takes a constant amount of time.  For these purposes, you can further assume that all primitive operations take the same time.  So just add them all up.

Then work out an algebraic formula for the number of operations performed as a function of your variables; e.g. your `x` and `y`.

The other thing is that in order to figure out the complexity you will need to understand *how* the code works.  Which can be a bit tricky when you have a *mystery function* like this one.

But even this one can be understood with some analytical thinking.  For example, you can work out how many times `x2` is going to be decremented in the inner loop ... by looking at the places where `x2` is assigned to.

---

<sup>1 - This only applies to complexity analysis.  If you are trying to estimate performance, these assumptions are not correct.  Different operations take different times, and in some cases the time taken for a given operation could vary depending on the context; e.g. whether or not you get a cache hit.  This is part of the reason that even roughly accurate *a priori* estimates of performance are really hard work.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the function is actually executed as written, the outer loop runs proportionally to `sqrt(y)` times, so the complexity of the entire function is `O(x * sqrt(y))`.

(It's worth noting that in real life, since the function has no side-effects, an optimizing compiler would probably replace it with a function that does nothing.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Btw I have modified the question by adding a similar method with another fractional expression in the exit condition of the loop. Could you have a look at this one as well?